# Best ORM to use without a PHP framework?

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

I was previously using Doctrine with CodeIgniter but want to just go back to just PHP without a framework(easier for me) but was still wanting an ORM to handle all my data persisting and data loading. What would be some good suggestions?

Comment: Propel and Doctrine are both well integrated with Symfony (1.x and 2.x) but work very well standalone. I use Propel both with and without symfony 1.x, and have stuck with it since it is well-maintained and the docs are great. If you know Doctrine already then there is an argument to stick with it, although you may find the pre-generated approach of Propel makes it a bit faster. There are some other PHP ORMs (see Wikipedia) but those are the big two, imo.

Comment: Actually i would suggest for you to instead start using [data mappers](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any reason not to keep using [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org)? (without CodeIgniter)

You could also check out [Propel](http://www.propelorm.org).